# How to solve an equation system in Mathematica 9

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Got a simple equation but Mathematica just can't get it:

```
Solve[{Sin[x] == y, x + y == 5}, {x, y}]

Error: this system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve
```

Am I using the right function? If not, what should I use?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly providing the domain of the variables as a parameter? (It may be breaking on imaginary numbers.) Also: Interestingly enough, WolframAlpha provides a unique solution for that query, as written. I do not have Mathematica on this computer or I would do a bit more digging for you.

Comment: I'm very new to Mathematica, how can I do that?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html Check Scope -> Systems of Real Equations and Inequalities in Several Variables (9) for examples.

Comment: `Solve[{Sin[x] == y, x + y == 5}, {x, y}, Reals]` will get the real-valued solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica knows a lot, but it surely doesn't know everything about math. When stuffs breakdown, you can try a few different approaches:

First let's graph it:

```
ContourPlot[{Sin[x] == y, x + y == 5}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

[image: contour plot]

It's a line intersecting a sinusoidal wave and it looks likes there is only one solution. The point is close to `(5,0)` so let's use the Newton method to find the root:

```
FindRoot[{Sin[x] == y, x + y == 5}, {x, 5}, {y, 0}]
```

This gives the answer `{x -> 5.61756, y -> -0.617555}`. You can verify it by replacing `x` and `y` in the equation with the values provided in the solution:

```
{Sin[x] == y, x + y == 5} /. {x -> 5.6175550052727`,y -> -0.6175550052726998`}
```

That gives `{True,True}` so the solution is correct. Interestingly, as another commenter pointed out, Wolfram Alpha gives the same solution when you type in this:

```
solve Sin[x]==y,x+y==5
```

You can access Wolfram Alpha directly from Mathematica by typing `==` at the beginning of a new line.